# Append Javascript Object to another in Angular 5

Tags: javascript

Hi how to append javascript objects to another one for example:

```
ObjectA = [
           {
            "id":"1",
            "name":"name 1"
           }
          ]

ObjectB = [
           {
            "id":"2",
            "name":"name 2"
           }
          ]
```

result would be like this:

```
Result = [
           {
            "id":"1",
            "name":"name 1"
           },
           {
            "id":"2",
            "name":"name 2"
           }
          ]
```

I tried to use Object.Assign() but it just overwrite the first object. Hope you can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to merge the two arrays
- [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge 2 objects

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign()` with a 3rd object

ie:

```
let result = {}
Object.assign(result, ObjectA, ObjectB)
```

With that method you dont modify ObjectA and ObjectB

**Edit** because your object are arrays :

```
  let result = ObjectA.concat(ObjectB)
```

`concat`does not modify the original objects

Comment: object.assign overwrites my first object

Comment: Yes but in the exemple i provide you we use a 3rd object instead of overwritting ObjectA; Anyway because you have array the concat soultion is more adapted

Answer (score 1):

Your Objects are inside an array. So you can use [array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```js
let ObjectA = [
           {
            "id":"1",
            "name":"name 1"
           }
          ]

let ObjectB = [
           {
            "id":"2",
            "name":"name 2"
           }
          ]
          
          
var result = ObjectA.concat(ObjectB);     

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi i use object in typescript so concat is useless

Comment: Your objects are not objects at the first place. They are arrays. And FYI, `Array.concat` works for typescript too. It is a `super set` of javascript.

Comment: yes but it gets an error, my object looks like this Object = [ {id:1,name:"name"}]

Comment: That's an array and not an Object. You may check `Array.isArray(Object)`. It returns true.